# How to avoid N+1 queries in scope with parameter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I met a N+1 issue in this situation:

`Library` has many `Programs`. Now I want to get all the programs located a certain country, so I have a code:

```
country = "US"
programs = @libraries.includes(:programs).map do |library|   
  library.programs.where(country: country)
end
```

But now there is N+1 problem:

```
Program Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."library_id" = $1 AND "programs"."country" = $2  [["library_id", 15], ["country", "US"]]
Program Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."library_id" = $1 AND "programs"."country" = $2  [["library_id", 73], ["country", "US"]]
Program Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."library_id" = $1 AND "programs"."country" = $2  [["library_id", 27], ["country", "US"]]
Program Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."library_id" = $1 AND "programs"."country" = $2  [["library_id", 177], ["country", "US"]]
Program Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."library_id" = $1 AND "programs"."country" = $2  [["library_id", 38], ["country", "US"]]
Program Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."library_id" = $1 AND "programs"."country" = $2  [["library_id", 51], ["country", "US"]]
Program Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."library_id" = $1 AND "programs"."country" = $2  [["library_id", 18], ["country", "US"]]
Program Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."library_id" = $1 AND "programs"."country" = $2  [["library_id", 20], ["country", "US"]]
Program Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."library_id" = $1 AND "programs"."country" = $2  [["library_id", 42], ["country", "US"]]
Program Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."library_id" = $1 AND "programs"."country" = $2  [["library_id", 39], ["country", "US"]]
```

**Update:**

My purpose is not to just filter the `programs`, but to use it. For example:

```
programs = @libraries.includes(:programs).each do |library|   
  if library.programs.where(country: country).size < 5
    puts "US programs are less than 5 so you can still add"
  end
end
```

Does anyone know how to solve the N+1 problem?

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing with this query `library.programs.where(country: country).size < 5`?

Comment: Hi @Pavan, my real problem is much more complex than my example and I just made example simple and easy understanding which may not have a real meaning. I updated the example code again and it's more meaningful I think.

Comment: Well, then I will update the code which will suite for your example

Answer (score 1):

You can **chain** the `where` query to the `includes` like below

```
programs = @libraries.includes(:programs).where(programs: {country: country})
```

which should solve the *N+1* problem.

See [*specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

**Update #1:**

You can simply do it like this

```
programs = @libraries.includes(:programs).where(programs: {country: country}).size < 5 #returns true or false

if programs #true
  puts "US programs are less than 5 so you can still add"
else #false
  #your code
end
```

**Update #2:**

This should do

```
programs_size = @libraries.includes(:programs).where(programs: {country: country}).map { |library| library.programs.size }
```

Which would perform only **one query** and **returns the size** of each `library.programs` matching that condition as **array** something like below

```
=> [5, 4, 7, 4, 6, 2, 1]
```

Now you can iterate over the `programs_size` array and perform the logic

```
programs_size.each do |ps|
  if ps < 5 #true
    puts "US programs are less than 5 so you can still add"
  else #false
    #your code
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan, my example may be simple so you used another way. Please see my update.

Comment: @Stephen Updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Pavan, your condition is to check the all collection less than 5, but my example is for each library, judge the programs if less than 5. It's different.

Comment: Hi Pavan, firstly thanks for your updated answer again. However, could you please not filter the programs? Actually, I will display **all the programs**, and each program may have action buttons. for example, if US `programs_size` less than 5, show "+US" button; if UK `programs_size` less than 5, show "+UK" button, etc.

Comment: @Stephen You can just remove the `where` from the above query and construct the logic according to your needs.